# laravel get foreign key data

Tags: php, laravel

I have controller

```
public function orders()
{
    return view('user.dashboard', ['order' => orders::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get(),]);
}
```

Code above prints out all orders from orders table based on user's id.

Orders table as well has product id column, which has a foreign key that links to products table.

The problem is I want to print out product name based on product id, but I don't know how.

Comment: Read about relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

If you have stablished your relations correctly,

```
Class Order extends Model{

   public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
   }
}
```

Then in your controller

```
public function orders()
{
    return view('user.dashboard', ['order' => orders::with('products')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get(),]);
}
```

Thus in every order you will have a collection with all products in that order.

Alternatively you load only those data needed in your view as the name of the product

```
public function orders()
{
    return view('user.dashboard', ['order' => orders::with('products.name')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get(),]);
}
```

Read more about eager loading in [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)